# i want to create labels using jquery through for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to create labels dynamically using for loops...this is what i have done and its not working kindly help me solve this issue

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    function create_labels(strt, end, overlay_body) {
        for (var i = strt; i < end; i++) {
            var labels=jQuery('<label id=lbl>hahahahha</label>');
            labels.appendTo(overlay_body);
        }
    }
});

var strt = 9;
var end = 17;

var overlay_body = jQuery('<div id=overlay_body></div>');
overlay_body.appendTo(document.body);
create_labels(strt,end,overlay_body);
```

Comment: The function is `get_labels` not `create_labels`, and it's hidden from the place where you're calling it because you nested it inside the `ready` callback. Also, where is the caller getting `strt` and `end`?

Comment: ...and please cleanly indent your code. Use http://jsbeautifier.org if you don't know how.

Comment: @squint check the edited question

Comment: *["The function is... hidden from the place where you're calling it because you nested it inside the ready callback...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955248/i-want-to-create-labels-using-jquery-through-for-loop#comment65264278_38955248) [and please cleanly indent your code"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955248/i-want-to-create-labels-using-jquery-through-for-loop#comment65264379_38955248)*

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to debug your javascript code.If you inspected the browser console you would know exactly what the problem is.To bring up the browser console in Google Chrome you can click Ctrl+Shift+J.

The problem is that the `create_labels()` function is not accessible **outside** of the jQuery load function.One way to fix this is to move the logic which calls this function inside the jQuery load:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    var strt = 9;
    var end = 17;

    function create_labels(strt, end, overlay_body) {
        for (var i = strt; i < end; i++) {
            var labels = jQuery('<label id=lbl>hahahahha</label><br />');
            labels.appendTo(overlay_body);
        }
    }

    var overlay_body = jQuery('<div id=overlay_body></div>');
    overlay_body.appendTo(document.body);
    create_labels(strt, end, overlay_body);
});
```